# Explanation on the use of the Hölder inequality in a proof

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces, calculus-of-variations, holder-inequality

I have to prove the Lemma 4 (Compactness) on page 116 of the article https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.2567.pdf. In particular, at the beginning of the proof, when the author says "Hence, by the Hölder inequality,
$$
\|Du_m\|_{L^m(\Omega)}=E_m(u_m, \Omega)^m\leq E_m(b, \Omega)^m=\|Db\|_{L^m(\Omega)}"
$$
(where $E_m(w)=\int\limits_{\Omega}|Dw|^m\ dx$), I don't understand where and how the Hölder inequality is applied. Can you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess Hölder is not applied in this line, since it seems to me, that just the minimising property of $u_m$ is used. However in the next inequality stated in the paper
$$\|D u_m\|_{L^k} \leq \|Du_m\|_{L^m} |\Omega|^{\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{m}}$$
Hölder's inequality has been applied and I think this is what the author of the paper meant.

Comment: Ok, anyway I don't understand why $\|Du_m\|_{L^m(\Omega)}=E_m(u_m, \Omega)^m$, in particular the power $m$ on $E_m$. Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: Maybe it is a typo and it should be $E_m(u_m,\Omega)^{\frac{1}{m}}$.

Comment: @humanStapedist, ok, I think the same thing. Thanks a lot.